Access Material's own Custom Properties from Shader Nodes
I'm making an add-on which imports a lot of custom properties for each Material. I want to be able to use those custom properties inside of the materials itself, and while I could use drivers, I'd want to be able to use the same node group in all of the materials, and it doesn't seem like drivers can be relative to the current material (though tell me if that's possible!)
Some properties are also arrays and it would be much more work to link those individually instead of just being able to use the Attribute node "Color" output.
It seems odd that I wouldn't be able to use the custom material properties from inside the material, I hope I'm just missing something.

I've found i can put "materials[0]" in the "Name:" section of the Attribute node and then get the attribute from that. This however only works if it's the first material on the object. This is fine in my current use case as there's only ever one material per object, but I'm still not entirely satisfied for future use cases where there may be more
